# D3.js Enter Animation

Tags: d3.js

Hey I just have a quick question:

How do I get a line/path to be drawn as it is parsed? I don't want it to appear all of the sudden, but rather have some transition() or related animation effect so that it will smoothly appear, almost like you are drawing it. Prefrably starting from the x axis to top, but top to down is ok too. Whichever is easier.

Depending on the order of my .attr arguments, the path will just appear and no transition, or dev tools says my path is not a function. Here is what I'm working with:

```
var max_line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return scale(d.local_max); })
  .y(function(d) { return yscale(d.Y); });    

svg.append('path')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' +(margins.left)+','+margins.top+')')
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .style('stroke-width', '4px')
  .style('stroke-dasharray', '5,3')
  .transition()
  .datum(data)
  .duration(3000)
  .attr('d', max_line);
```

Aside from the animation on enter issue, bonus points for whoever can tell me why my stroke dash array doesn't get applied. It always appears as a boring, solid line.

My question may differ from those previously asked because it's not so easy to have enter animations in conjunction with stroke-dasharray.

Comment: would you care to explain how to use smooth start to end animation with a dashed styled path? That is to say, instead of animating with a solid line, actually animating with a dashed line from beginning to end. So that at 0 it's a dashed line, and at the end, it's still a dashed line, with constant spacing. Say "stroke-dasharray",  "5,3" throughout the animation? Every other example uses a solid line animation. I need a dashed line animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make a path like this:

```
   var path = svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", max_line)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', 'white')
      .style('stroke-width', '4px')
      .attr("fill", "none");
```

get the total length of the path:

```
 var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
```

Now make the stroke-dasharray using the `totallength` (done so that the line is not visible). Later transition the `stroke-dashoffset` from total length to 0 as shown in the snippet below.

```
path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Comment: Great work, I'm still having issues with the stroke-dasharray appearing, but the animation part is working perfectly now. I wondering about the two occurences of .attr('fill', 'none') Maybe that's why the dash array isn't working? Or do we actually need 2?

Comment: the  `.attr('fill', 'none') ` is for setting the fill attribute of the path..may be you can make it  `.attr('fill', 'red') ` to see the fill path. That should explain for itself.

Comment: Yea, that part I understand. I meant why are there two of those in the snippet? I'm just trying to trouble shoot why the stroke-dasharray is not working and I thought maybe it had something to do with that?

Comment: well it has nothing to do with `stroke-dasharray` may be something else

Comment: Ok, I think I grasp your solution a bit more. I've seen others like it, and it seems to be 'drawing' the line from bottom to top using the stroke-dasharray attribute itself, is that right? I thought it was some x,y coordinate transition to draw it. My final follow up question, is: Is it possible to have the line drawn with dashed lines throughout the animation? I ask because, in terms of style, I prefer the dashed line effect.